# For any projects using functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming

I have a free time and would like to do functional programming and learn some functional programming language.

But as we know the best theory it is practice. In this regard, I would like to know in which sector is most often used functional programming? I understand if the project is written in a functional language that is somehow justified. Therefore, such a question: what kind of projects easier and more profitable to write in functional languages?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Compilers are often referred to as the "killer app"** for functional languages with algebraic data types, like Haskell and ML.  I have written compilers in a procedural language, in an object oriented language, and in functional languages, and a functional language is *worlds* better.

A compiler is also a relatively attractive project in that you can pick up, say, Andrew Appel's book on the used market, and build the whole thing yourself—just be sure to compile a very simple language.

Answer (score 3):

interpreters, hand-written recursive descendant parsers, program analyzers

Answer (score 2):

AI, data processing, scientific/financial/computationally intensive applications.

Answer (score 1):

Financials, Statistics, and Scientific Computation are the three areas where Functional Programming are used the heaviest.

You could always throw together a simple statistics calculation package that works against one of the various social networks out there. An F# stats application against the StackOverflow would be an interesting project...

Comment: The *three* main areas where Functional Programming are used the heaviest are Financials, Statistics, Scientific Computation and a Fanatical Devotion to the Pope!

Comment: @Chris - Doh! I updated the answer with Statistics and forgot to update the count. Heh.